# How I fixed the small white borders on the left and right on vuejs

Tags: css, vue.js

Hi everyone I stuck at this page 2 day and I see border in page and I want to not see this border in case we use vuejs3
[photo of web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Was1.jpg)

```
    <template>
  <div class="home">
    <section id="lamyPage" class="background-image">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="../assets/Lamy_logo_png.png" alt="logolamy" height="350" width="350">
        <h1>Test1</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="lamyService">
      <h1>Test2</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="lamyPortfolio">
      <h1>Test3</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="lamyAboutme">
      <h1>Test4</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="lamyTeamDev">
      <h1>Test5</h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.home {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#lamyPage {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0ea5e9, #65C2F5);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#lamyPage img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

/* Reset the background color for the other sections */
#lamyService,
#lamyPortfolio,
#lamyAboutme,
#lamyTeamDev {
  background: white;
  color: initial;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

I see border in left and rignt anywhere and background is not full How I fix it body isn't work and in section id lamyPage not work How I delete border in this section or make to same color in this section

Thank!!

Comment: You'll need to use the DOM inspector of your browser's dev tools and [debug your CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Debugging_CSS).  Could be an issue of width, padding, margin, or something else.

Comment: In white border I see it's body

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  With the DOM inspector you should be able to figure out what element is causing the white area and what CSS properties need to change.  If you need help figuring out how to write the CSS code in Vue just add the relevant info from the inspector to your question.  Have you used the DOM/page inspector before?

Comment: Yes and I use dom inspector to debug css and I see border white left and right from body I want to change to full frame only in section lamyPage

Comment: border is a specific CSS property.  do you mean border, or do you mean something else?  if there's a border, you do `border: none`.  If there's margin you do `margin: 0`.  The white area is caused by some specific CSS that you can change.  First step is figuring it out in the inspector.  Inspect elements, find anything with border, margin, padding, etc. and set things to `none` or `0`.  Without your full app it'll be very hard for anyone to do it for you.  Your answer is in the inspector.  Find the correct element, find the correct property, apply the change.

Comment: thx for everyone I see in style scope just delete scope to change <style>